# Decompose a number in prime numbers

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, primes, factorization

How can I find a number within the interval (from 1 to ***given number***) which is when decomposed into prime numbers has the maximum amount of them.

***Example:***

**Input: 9**

**Output: 8**

**Explanation:**

8 = 2 * 2 * 2 (3 primes)

7 = 7 * 1 (1 prime)

6 = 3 * 2 ( 2 primes)

And so on... At the end, we'll see that 8 has the greatest amount of primes in decomposition.

**Specification:**

If there're several numbers having the same amount of primes in decomposition, return the greatest of them.

Comment: is there a question or are you just showing off your coding style?

Comment: Please add another example. Not clear to me at least

Comment: dude, don't you see that the task's output and mine do not match?

Comment: 4 also decomposes to two prime numbers (2 x 2). Why shouldn't that be the correct output?

Comment: @Greg in that case, return the maximum number

Comment: It is not clear from your question what you are asking. Nor is it clear if your code works.

Comment: "_don't you see that the task's output and mine do not match?_" I don't. Where did you post the output of your code?

Comment: @Greg if my code confuses you, pay attention just to task. It works but not in thorough way. It needs additions to return the expected output

Comment: @csmckelvey I explained how my code works... it's not so difficult to predict the output

Comment: It's also not so difficult to just post the output of your code instead of asking us free helpers to do more than we have to. If you want an answer you should be making it as easy as possible for all the volunteers here.

Comment: @csmckelvey okay, added

Comment: i guess now everything is clear enough :)

Comment: `const f = num => { let twoEnd = 2 ** Math.floor(Math.log2(num)); let threeEnd = twoEnd / 2 * 3; return threeEnd <= num ? threeEnd : twoEnd; }`, not absolutely sure this works btw, but sounds like it would.

Comment: @ASDFGerte it works, but it'd be great if you explain how you came up with this solution

Comment: Where is this problem from anyways? are there unit tests?

Comment: @ASDFGerte it's from local computer science competitions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I think I understood your requirement.

Here's a simple script to do what you have asked.

```
//source of this function: https://jsfiddle.net/JamesOR/RC7SY/

function getAllFactorsFor(remainder) {
    var factors = [], i;

    for (i = 2; i <= remainder; i++) {
        while ((remainder % i) === 0) {
            factors.push(i);
            remainder /= i;
        }
    }

    return factors;
}

function calculate(x) {

    lastFactorCount = 0;
    highestNumber = 0;

    while (x) {
        currentCount = getAllFactorsFor(x).length;

        if (currentCount > lastFactorCount) {
            lastFactorCount = currentCount;
            highestNumber = x;
        }

        x--;
    }

    return highestNumber;
}

console.log(calculate(7)); //output: 6
console.log(calculate(11)) //output: 8
```

This pass the two test cases you have given. I borrowed the `getAllFactorsFor()` function from a jsfiddle I found since we don't need to reinvent anything ;)

`calculate()` function takes in an input number, then it loops through every number from x to 0, counting how many factors it has, and it keeps track of the last factor count while decrementing x in each iteration.

Finally it outputs the number with highest factor count. Simple.

Hope it helps!!

Comment: Solving O(1) problems in O(n²). Also, if you want to get all factors with a loop like that, iterate to `Math.sqrt(remainder)` and add a simple check for the last prime, making it O(sqrt(n)) instead of O(n) (where n is the number itself). Unless you want to implement general number field sieve or similar at least.

Comment: Interesting! but as I have mentioned in my answer, I borrowed the function to count factors from another source, and gave the proper credit ;) I was only concerned about giving the clue to the OP on what he's missing, not on how to actually implement the factor decomposition method. Anyway, I would like to see how you would implement the solution to this problem with a O(1) complexity as you have mentioned in your comment.?

Comment: I posted an answer 11 hours ago, a comment with the same code 12 hours ago ;)

Comment: Is it giving the exact solution the OP asked? and with O(1) complexity? ;) I do not criticize your answer. But saw only a function which returns factors (didn't check whether it works, but I'm sure it doesn't answer the original question)

Comment: Apart from the theory, `for (let i = 2; i < 3000; i++) { if (f(i) !== calculate(i)) alert(i); }` doesn't give a single alert, it returns the same result as your function at least for the first 3000 integers.

Comment: Please edit your answer and provide the proper one ;)

Comment: If there is a mistake with my solution, i'd be happy to know - you are talking as if there is one, but don't actually mention any.

Comment: @ASDFGerte please read the question and see if it answers what OP has asked.

Comment: Strictly speaking, there is no question. Realistically speaking, as far as i can see, it should. I don't like what you are doing. If there is a problem, express it, and don't beat around the bush.

Comment: @ASDFGerte "Find a number from 1 to N which is when decomposed in prime numbers has the maximum amount of them." [I have no problem with you nor your answer. I didn't check your answer either because I don't have time. Only OP knows why he hasn't accepted your answer.]

Comment: Which part of my comment, that the function i gave returns the same value as your `calculate` for at least the first 3000 integers, and in theory for all integers greater or equal than two, did you not understand? Also please, give an example where my function is returning the wrong output.

Comment: @ASDFGerte Please add an input and output example. (Sorry I don't have time to check  it myself)

Comment: "I would like to see how you would implement the solution to this problem with a O(1) complexity as you have mentioned in your comment.?" - when my answer was there hours beforehand. "Please edit your answer and provide the proper one", "please read the question and see if it answers what OP has asked", while no problem is given, then change to "I didn't check your answer". Then suddenly ask for example input and output. I came to the conclusion you are just wasting my time - i don't like that.

Comment: @ASDFGerte not really, you are the one who started commenting on this. So I just replied to you ;)

Comment: Ok, I just checked it and your solution seems to be really good. I honestly didn't have to time to check other answers. My answer to this question was just a follow along to what OP had asked. I didn't want to spend much time on working on the factorizations. You have done a great job!

Answer (score 0):

Notice that after 2 and 3, the next prime is 5, which is bigger than 2*2 (obviously). Therefore, using 2*2 will ALWAYS be better for amount of prime factors, than any higher prime. The number with the highest amount of 2 as prime factors which is still lower or equal is `2 ** Math.floor(Math.log2(num))`. The only thing we need to check is whether replacing the last prime factor 2 with a 3 will still be below the number, as that may happen, and would yield a bigger number. Note again, using more than one 3 would be 3*3 = 9 > 8 = 2*2*2, which cannot be a solution again. All of that together yields that the solution should simply be

```
const f = num => {
  let twoEnd = 2 ** Math.floor(Math.log2(num));
  let threeEnd = twoEnd / 2 * 3;
  return threeEnd <= num ? threeEnd : twoEnd;
}
```

Some handling for numbers smaller than 2 may be necessary, depending on the circumstances.